# R3- Corda transaction without notary signature

Tags: corda

I am new to Corda and I want to know the role of the notary in detail. As per the document it says, for example a transaction happens between Party A and Party B , notary will sign the transaction and the role of the notary is to prevent double-spending. Can we have a transaction without notary signature. In TransactionBuilder class its saying var notary: Party? Notary used for the transaction. If null, this indicates the transaction DOES NOT have a notary. As per the syntax we can set it as null and if we put it as null whether the transaction will be valid and how the corda prevent double-spending. Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notary signature is only required in the following cases:

1. If your transaction has inputs: To testify that those inputs were not consumed, preventing double spends.
2. If your transaction has reference states: To testify that those reference states were not consumed, preventing the use of "out-dated" reference data.
3. If your transaction has a time-window: To testify that the transaction was finalized within the specified time-window.

You can see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/506b7609a385c3706a3f878c564ad48c712effaf/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L238-L242) the function `needsNotarySignature()` inside `FinalityFlow` which proves the above points.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Adel's answer on the notary signature requirement for the cases mentioned by him. To add to that, a transaction is needed to be associated with a notary, it should not be null.

One case where one might think that a notary is not required is an issuance of a state. Actually, the signature of notary is not required, however, the transaction still needs a notary since the state needs to be tagged to a notary to prevent any double-spend when the state is consumed.

In case no notary is attached to it the state can be sent to different notaries and that could lead to double spend.

You could validate this in the TransactionBuilder's addOutput method:

```
fun addOutputState(
    state: ContractState,
    contract: ContractClassName = requireNotNullContractClassName(state),
    constraint: AttachmentConstraint = AutomaticPlaceholderConstraint
): TransactionBuilder {
    checkNotNull(notary) { "Need to specify a notary for the state, or set a default one on TransactionBuilder initialisation" }
    addOutputState(state, contract, notary!!, constraint = constraint)
    return this
}
```

Comment: Where we can use notary as null 
https://api.corda.net/api/corda-os/4.4/html/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.transactions/-transaction-builder/index.html
TransactionBuilder class its saying var notary: Party? Notary used for the transaction. If null, this indicates the transaction DOES NOT have a notary

Comment: I guess that couldn't be done. All transactions should have a notary as far as I know.One scenario where you may not need a notary is perhaps when your application just needs to issue states and you don't care if it gets consumes and it doesn't need a notary. To make that technically feasible though you may have to subclass the txBuilder.

Comment: So you means to say that in TransactionBuilder the parameter value can be null in the case of just needs to issue states. Otherwise at syntax level it can be made as not null value right?

Comment: No exarctly in the TransactionBuilder, but you would need to subclass and update the addOutput() method to allow that behavior. As you can see in the code in the answer, it doesn't allow null notary.

Comment: @AshutoshMeher so why there's a TransactionBuilder constructor where Notary can be null?